# I can't understand the output of this program

Tags: c, pointers

My program is given below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  int x=30,*y,*z;
  y=&x;
  z=y;
  *y++=*z++;  //what does this mean?
  x++;          
  printf("%d %d",y,z);  
  return 0;
}
```

What is the meaning of this statement: `*y++=*z++`?

Comment: `y` and `z` both point to `x`, so you're assigning `x` to itself. Then you're incrementing both pointers. Then you're causing undefined behavior by passing them to `printf`, but using the `%d` conversion, which expects `int`s, not pointers (to print pointers, cast them to `void *` and convert with `%p`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm rusty on this: is it legal even to make them point beyond allocated space ?

Comment: @cnicutar: Yes. Pointing one past the end of an array is allowed as long as you don't dereference the pointer, and (C99, §6.5.6/7): "For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to:

```
*y = *z;
y++;
z++;
```

> I cant understand the output of this program

You're printing pointers, there's not much to understand.

---

- You should be using `%p` instead of `%d` when printing pointers
- You're moving beyond the known universe when you increment those pointers

Answer (score 3):

`y` and `z` are pointers, and the expressions `y++` and `z++` are using the postfix operators, so both increments will happen *after* the assignment.

This statement does 3 things:

1. Assigns to the value pointed to by `y` the same value pointed to by `z`: `*y = *z`.
2. Increments the `y` pointer. Now `y` points to the *next* `int` in memory.
3. Increments the `z` pointer. Now `z` points to the *next* `int` in memory.

The last two would be bad if `y` and `z` were used after the statement: `y` and `z` now point to uninitialized memory that doesn't belong to the code.

Comment: postfix operator has higher precedence than *. So would it not increment the z pointer first and then dereference it?

Comment: sorry i got this. the effect of postfix operator is felt only after executing the instruction. feeling dumb now !!!

Answer (score 1):

`*y++=*z++;` - This is just assigning the values stored in pointer `z` to the `*y`. After this its incrementing both `y` and `z` pointer. After this statement dereferencing of both `z` and `y` may leads to crash(an undefined behaviour).

These kind of statement is used in string copy implementation

```
void my_strcpy(char *dest, char* src)
{
   while((*dest++ = *src++));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the same as:

```
*y = *z;
++z;
++y;
```

Answer (score 0):

This simply assigns the value of the object pointed to by `y` to that of the object pointed to by `z`, then increments both pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It will  simply assign the value of the object pointed to by y to that of the object pointed to by z, and finally it increments both pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Variables `y` and `z` are pointers to integers, and in this case, point to the address of variable x.

The following lines set the value of `y` to the address of `x` (i.e. `&x` gives you the address of `x).

```
y=&x;
z=y
```

The next line, `*y++=*z++;` doesn't exactly make sense and may or may not compile depending on the compiler used.  In the case of GCC 4.3.2, it gives the following error.

```
foo.c:7: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’)
```

It looks like you are trying to do pointer arithmetic, but got the operator precedence a little mixed up.  Are you trying to increment the value pointed to by `z` after assigning the pre-increment value to a location?

Comment: You are getting that error because you missed the semicolon for the statement "z=y"

Answer (score 0):

```
*y++=*z++;  //wat  does this mean?
```

The above results in undefined behaviour (multiple modifications before the next sequence point).